# Remove plastic bag logo

Tags: repair

How do I remove the plastic bag a logo that was in bedded in my leather car seats. My car is brand new and I can't get it out. I tried rubbing alcohol,  now Polish remover. Please help[image]

Comment: take it to a professional cleaner

Comment: A logo that transferred from a plastic bag to a seat? What was in the bag or was it there for an extended time or extreme temperature / conditions? More info could be helpful to what caused the mark on leather seats.

Comment: It was a Dillard department store plastic bag filled with wet clothes and left in sun prob 4 hours then in garage all night. I just bought the car and it's a lease. Can I send a pic

Comment: I live in Florida and it was about 90 degrees outside

Comment: Try apple cider vinegar.

Answer (score 1):

Try different solvents on the *bag* to see what removes the ink. The try an effective solvent on an inconspicuous bit of upholstery to see if it damages it.

You might need to make a paste of the solvent and an absorbent material, such as diatomaceous earth (used in swimming pool filters), to keep the solvent in place and to wick away the stain.

Look online for other tips on leather cleaning, e.g. [Bob Vila's site](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/how-to-clean-leather-furniture/).

Answer (score 0):

That's happened to me before and I used bug spray, sponge to scrub, and a rag to wipe off. It worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like Goo Gone in a small area.  But also check out available [leather cleaners](https://www.autogeek.net/searchresults.html?catalog=autogeek&query=leather%20cleaner&submit=Go&.autodone=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.autogeek.net%2Fleather-master-auto-care.html#?keywords=leather%20cleaner&search_return=all&page=2) to look for something made for more than just regular maintenance.

I also own [this attachment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001TR2F9M), which I use when applying cleaner / conditioner to leather.  You do need a drill to attach it to.

If you don't plan / want to do any sort of detail work on your own, it's probably not worth investing in the product and any accessories, and instead just bring it to a good local detail shop.